# How can I take part of a file txt in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file.txt ending with this:

```
HGVSp : HGVS protein sequence name

HGVS_OFFSET : Indicates by how many bases the HGVS notations for this variant 
have been shifted

Uploaded_variation     Location        Allele  Gene    Feature Feature_type    Consequence     cDNA_position   CDS_position    Protein_positi
CYP2C9:c.121A>G 10:96698560     G       ENSG00000138109 ENST00000260682 Transcript      missense_variant        133     121     41      N/D
CYP2C9:c.121A>G 10:96698560     G       ENSG00000233377 ENST00000424125 Transcript      downstream_gene_variant -       -       -       -
CYP2C9:c.121A>G 10:96698560     G       ENSG00000138109 ENST00000461906 Transcript      non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcri
CYP2C9:c.121A>G 10:96698560     G       ENSG00000138109 ENST00000473496 Transcript      upstream_gene_variant   -       -       -       -
```

I would like a new file1.txt like this:

```
chr10 (tab) 96698560 (tab) CYP2C9:c.121A>G
```

`chr10` is the number after a>g and before ':' and `96698560` is the number after ':'

so:

```
chr10      96698560       CYP2C9:c.121A>G
```

How can I do This?

Comment: Take some time to better format your question; then post what you have tried until now.

Comment: I don't know how to do for that i asked

Comment: You should format better your question. You say "chr10<-(it's the number)...". What is "chr"? Explain. Then I see 2 times that "A>G". You mean the output file should contains all the lines containing A>G, I suppose. Explain again. Your input file should be enclosed in tags to show better how is made. Anyway, take a look to awk, and perhaps perl. If your file is not too long, even bash could do.

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

It might not the perfect solution but hope this helps.

```
tail -200 FILENAME | grep CYP2C | awk '{ print "chr10\t",$2,"\t",$1}' | sed 's/10://g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it in awk:

```
awk -F"[ :]" 'printnext==1{print "chr"$3"\011"$4"\011"$1":"$2; printnext=0}$1=="Uploaded_variation"{printnext=1}' <yourfile>
```

This will split each record by a space or a colon into multiple fields. We test each record for the first field equal to "Uploaded_variation" if we get a hit we set the variable "printnext" to 1. If printnext is "1" then we print out the record in the format you described and set printnext back to 0.